# Remove first occurrence of duplicate lines

Tags: regex, pcre

This pattern (with `mis` flags on) keeps the last occurrence of duplicate lines

```
^(\w+)\R(?=.*?^\1$)
```

like in this [example](http://regex101.com/r/rP4lH9/2)
How to keep the first occurrence instead using Regex only
example

```
Apple
Banana
TEST
apple
Cherry
banana
bananA
Var
cherry
applE
cherrY
```

Result :

```
Apple
Banana
TEST
Cherry
Var
```

the point here is to keep the original order of entries and remove duplicates.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? could you post the example here along with the expected output with some explanation?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with replace all operation (it is possible when the string is scanned from right to left - can be turned on in .NET). Given `ABAB`, if you want to remove the second A, you need to consume the first B, which will prevent B from being removed at all. By the way, you probably want this regex instead: http://regex101.com/r/rP4lH9/2

Comment: As [nhahtdh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh) said, you can't do this with pure PCRE. What language are you using? I think it can be done without regex or partially with regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with a single regex or `s///` regex replacement unless the interpreter supports dynamic-width lookbehinds.

I'm going to solve this in vim, whose regex interpreter actually supports dynamic lookbehind, but it's really obtuse, so I'll first recreate the delete-first-instance variation (`^(\w+)\R(?=.*?^\1$)` in the question).

The `:%s/^\(\w\+\)\n\ze\%(^\w\+\n\)*\1$//ig` vim command (`:`) will, for all lines (`%`), use substitute (`s/…//ig`) to remove a case-insensitive global match of a regex with lines starting with (`^`) a capture (`\(…\)`) of 1+ word characters (`\w\+`) followed by a line break (`\n`). The rest of the match is a zero-width look-ahead (`\ze` means "zero-width end" and `\zs…` is akin to `(?=…)` at the end of a PCRE regex). We then skip over zero or more non-capturing groups (`\%(…\)*`) containing words on their own line before matching that original capture (`\1`). Because of the `\ze`, that part is not removed when we remove that first instance, leaving us with:

```
TEST
bananA
Var
applE
cherrY
```

(I hate writing vimscript and vim regular expressions. I really don't know how you convinced me here...)

Here is a somewhat acceptable solution. (I say somewhat because the `/g` isn't global enough.)

`:%s/^\(\w\+\)\n\%(\w\+\n\)*\zs\1\n//ig` uses a very similar composition to the previous delete-first-instance command. I've changed the `\ze` to `\zs` ("zero-width start", like PCRE `\K`). This is, in effect, a variable width look-behind. (Yes, I could theoretically have made it look more like `(?<=…)` with vim's `\%(…\)\@<=` but that's uglier and I couldn't get it working.) That "skip" group is moved to stay in the zero-width side.

Despite the zero-width nature, this needs to be run once per replacement (4x in this case). I believe this is because the match is set on the final instance, so each replacement has to consume space up to the final match (this regex is greedy) and then step backwards, but after the first replacement, it doesn't know to iterate backwards to the next capture.

After four runs, you'll be left with:

```
Apple
Banana
TEST
Cherry
Var
```

(Yes, that's a trailing blank line that crept in. That's probably an artifact of removing both `apple` and `cherrY` in the same action.)

---

Here's a more practical solution using Javascript, with a regex doing as much of the work as possible:

```js
test = "Apple\nBanana\nTEST\napple\nCherry\nbanana\nbananA\nVar\ncherry\ncherrY\n";
while ( test != ( test = test.replace(/^(\w+\n)((?:\w+\n)*)\1/mig, "$1$2") ) ) 1;
```

All of the logic lives inside the condition of the `while` loop, which basically says "perform this replacement and loop until it doesn't do anything" by comparing the string (`!=`) before replacement to the string after replacement. The loop means we don't have to deal with zero widths since we start over again on each iteration (regex would otherwise resume where it left off, thus the need for zero width).

The regex itself is just captures a word on its own line (`^(\w+\n)`) and then matches zero or more other words (`((?:\w+\n)*)`), then the captured word again (`\1`).

The `while` loop's body is empty (`1` is a no-op) because the condition contains all of the logic. Javascript doesn't require braces when given a single command, but this would more formally be
`while ( test != ( test = test.replace(…) ) ) { true; }`

This loops four times (you can count by setting `i=0` before the loop and changing the `1` to `i++` inside the loop) and then leaves `test` as:

```
Apple
Banana
TEST
Cherry
Var
```